# Allow user in a chrooted shell to use a sudo command

Tags: server, 16.04, sudo, chroot

I have a user `chroot`ed to a directory, and everything is working smoothly. I want a group this user is in to be able to restart a single process that's being managed by `supervisor`, however, and I can't figure out how.

I've added this line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
%mygroupname ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/supervisorctl restart myprocessname
```

I copied `/usr/bin/sudo` to the same path in the `chroot` environment. I also copied all of its dependencies to the relevant places (found using `ldd /usr/bin/sudo`).

I've gathered that `sudo` uses a *ton* of additional files on the system, and I've copied them to the `chroot` environment. I'm stuck now, however, and can't get past this error. What am I missing?

`sudo` log (line breaks for readability):

```
Nov 10 20:29:04 sudo[3593] pam_setcred: Failure setting user credentials @
                           sudo_pam_begin_session()
                           /build/sudo-1bDJzQ/sudo-1.8.16/plugins/sudoers/auth/pam.c:274

Nov 10 20:29:04 sudo[3593] pam_open_session: Module is unknown @
                           sudo_pam_begin_session()
                           /build/sudo-1bDJzQ/sudo-1.8.16/plugins/sudoers/auth/pam.c:283
```

Is this a completely stupid idea in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than trying to copy the sudo binary and its dependencies into the chroot, it might be easier to have a script running as root that checks when a file exists and restarts the process.

That script might be something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
restartfile="restartprocess"
while :
do
   for user in /home/*
   do
      if [ -f $user/$restartfile ]
      then
         supervisorctl restart myprocessname
         rm $user/$restartfile
      fi
   done
   sleep 5 #Adjust file checking time interval
done
```

(This also assumes the user is chrooted to a folder in /home)

Once this script is running as root, the chrooted user would just have to run one of the following commands to create an empty file (called `restartprocess`) in its home directory (you could add `~/` before the file name):

```
touch restartprocess
```

```
echo > restartprocess
```

```
> restartprocess
```

And the process would be restarted.

Comment: Oh this is beautiful, I never would have thought of this. Thank you so much, it works perfectly!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!